# Re-Identification while using YOLOv8 + ByteTrack on real time RTSP stream

Tags: rtsp, yolov8, tracker, ultralytics

I'm working on a project which requires vehicles to be detected real time and get the number of vehicles at any instance of time. I am using YOLOv8 + ByteTrack for this purpose. However, when I run my model on the real time RTSP stream, each vehicle is being Re-ID'd a lot (Same vehicle is assigned multiple ID's). But I noticed that if I download a small clip of my RTSP stream and then run my model on it, ByteTrack does a pretty decent job in preventing Re-Identification. Any idea why the real time RTSP stream is not able to produce the same results?